# Use Swift 2.2 with iOS 9.2 and watchOS 2.1?

Tags: ios9.2, xcode7.3, ios9.3, swift2

Now that `Swift 2.2 / iOS 9.3 / watchOS 2.2` is out, can I update an app using `Xcode 7.3` and still work on a `iOS 9.2` device?

For example, if I started using `#selector(someFunc)` instead of `selector("someFunc")`, will this crash on a `iOS 9.2` device?

Answer (score 1):

iOS SDK is maintained to be backward-compatible (though I don't know, how far back). You can take a look at page [SDK Compatibility Guide, Base SDK and Deployment Target Settings](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Configuring/configuring.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000163i-CH1-SW1) to read about "Base SDK" and "Deployment Target" project settings.

The latest language version (either Swift or Objective-C) can also be used with older iOS versions, because, no matter what the language is, the compiler will generate effectively the same machine-code at the end. There could be nuances like lack of some OS features (e.g. ARC is fully supported starting from iOS 5, though it's pretty much compiler/language feature).

It may be also interesting to read [Xcode 7.3 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051) to get the list of new features and changes. This document does not states that some older iOS versions are no more supported.